# How can I update content automatically every X hours?

Tags: rules

I have a content type that I want updated every five hours. When some nodes haven't been updated, the I'd like to alert a content admin with a warning message containing the list of nodes that have not been updated, e.g. :

> [node:title] has not been updated! please update

The nodes can also be displayed in a block

Comment: `The nodes can also be displayed in a block` You should do this with Views as Shawn mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be completely driven by Views & [Views System Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_system_message) module.

You can create a block view for node content of type XXX that has an added **Filter Criteria** *Content: Updated date* with the **Operator** set to *Is less than or equal to* and the **Value type** set to an *An offset...* of "-5 hours" **Value**. That will get you a block view of content XXX that was edited more than 5 hours ago.

The last part, the alert message, can be added in the **Header** area by selecting the *Global: System message* type and setting the parameters to your liking. Once the block view is saved, you can add the block to whatever region you feel most appropriate.